# Why The Drop out seems Counter Productive in the NoteBook here?

Tags: python, deep-learning

https://github.com/Gelesh/DeepLearingVanilaCode/blob/main/Dropout_MoreData.ipynb

This NoteBook Illustrates Vanila Coding and Drop Out.
However, with the examples quoted there , 2-3 data sets, it seems Dropout is counter productive.

Is there any mistake in the data set ? How to Correct it ?

[image: Below is the Cost of Drop out VS non DropOut on a Data Set to identify Cat]